# tableView editing syle in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have my tableView so that when you swipe left on a cell it gives you the option to delete the cell, I have it so that only the original poster of the cell can actually delete the cell, but I want it so that it doesn't let you swipe left to give the delete option if the user isn't the original poster of the cell. For example, in the screenshot, delete button pops up when I swipe left on a cell, but my code doesn't allow it to delete because I am not the original poster. I want it so that the delete button will not appear when I swipe left on a post that is not mine.[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(editingStyle == .delete && messageArray[indexPath.row].postedBy == (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!){
            DataService.instance.removeMessage(withKey: messageArray[indexPath.row].key)
            messageArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        if messageArray[indexPath.row].postedBy == (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)! {
            return .delete
        }
        return .none
    }
```

Use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle` to decide which cell can be delete.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put the condition that the cell can be edited into this method

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
       // This mean if the post is not original post then the delete button will appear
        let postCanBeDeleted = !messageArray[indexPath.row].isOriginalPoster
        return postCanBeDeleted
 }
```

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: You define a bool variable to decide whether your post can be deleted or not the return on that method. Let's see my update answer.

Comment: so I set that isOriginalPoster in cellForRow but it still allows me to make that edit

Comment: It should not be in that way. You need calculate the logic isOriginalPoster in your models (which are stored in messageArray). Or you can test by condition like `let postCanBeDeleted = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)`; this means if index of row is even then delete button will be showed.